# glTranslatef and mouse clicks - gluUnProject

Tags: java, opengl, mouseevent, jogl

## Please see bottom of question for the current solution I have gone for, thanks to Finlaybob, elect, gouessej

An appeal to the Elders of OpenGL.... I am having big problems with detecting the relative position of a mouse click on my textured plane.

I am making a game where I am drawing a single large square and texturing it with a large generated map texture. The view is always top down and you can only currently move the X Y and Z coordinates of that square.

[Screenshot of the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUlpm.jpg)

**OpenGL init**

```
screenRatio = (float)screenW / (float)screenH;
System.out.println("init");
glu = new GLU();
GL2 gl2 = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
gl2.glShadeModel( GL2.GL_SMOOTH );
gl2.glHint( GL2.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL2.GL_NICEST );
gl2.glClearColor( 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f );
gl2.glDepthMask(false);
gl2.glEnable(GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

**Set camera position**

```
gl2.glViewport(0, 0, 1024, 768);
gl2.glMatrixMode( GL2.GL_PROJECTION );
gl2.glLoadIdentity();
glu.gluPerspective( 45, screenRatio, 1, 100 );
glu.gluLookAt( 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 );
gl2.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
gl2.glLoadIdentity();
```

**Move position to start drawing the map**

```
// typical camera coord example:
// CENTRE: 0.0f, 0.0f, 10f
// FULL ZOOM OUT AND TOP LEFT: -25f, 25f, 40f

// move position
gl2.glTranslatef( -cameraX, -cameraY, -cameraZ );
```

I suspect the glTranslatef z-coord may be a suspect. As I am drawing the square 40f ( for example ) away from the origin

**Map vertex information**

```
// here are the coordinates/dimensions of my textured square ( my map )
float[] vertexArray = {
    -25f,  25f,
     25f,  25f,
     25f, -25f,
     25f, -25f,
};
```

**Mouse click position calculation**

"Borrowed" from java-tips 1628-how-to-use-gluunproject-in-jogl.html

```
int x = mouse.getX(), y = mouse.getY();
int viewport[] = new int[4];
double mvmatrix[] = new double[16];
double projmatrix[] = new double[16];
int realy = 0;
double wcoord[] = new double[4];

gl2.glGetIntegerv(GL2.GL_VIEWPORT, viewport, 0);
gl2.glGetDoublev(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, mvmatrix, 0);
gl2.glGetDoublev(GL2.GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projmatrix, 0);

realy = viewport[3] - (int) y - 1;

glu.gluUnProject(
    (double) x,
    (double) realy,
    0.0, // I have experimented with having this as 1.0 also
    mvmatrix, 0,
    projmatrix, 0,
    viewport, 0,
    wcoord, 0
);
```

Experimenting with the near/far bit ( 3rd param of gluUnProject ) seems to produce a better effect but there seems to be no sweet spot ( the best I found was 0.945 )

**I would very much like mCX, mCY to be relative to the rendered map coordinates ( -25f - 25f ) regardless of Z position**

```
mCX = (float)wcoord[0];
mCY = (float)wcoord[1];
```

**Draw a rectangle at the translated coordinates**

```
gl2.glColor3f(1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
gl2.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);
gl2.glVertex2f( mCX-0.1f, mCY+0.1f );
gl2.glVertex2f( mCX+0.1f, mCY+0.1f );
gl2.glVertex2f( mCX+0.1f, mCY-0.1f );
gl2.glVertex2f( mCX-0.1f, mCY-0.1f );
gl2.glEnd();
```

Currently the coordinates work well in relation to x & y translation, if I click the very centre of the screen it will draw a box approximately in the correct place regardless of my glTranslatef movement. If I click away from the centre of the screen I see an exponential offset.

**Demonstration of exponential offset**

When I click the very dead centre of the screen it will draw this mauve square exactly around the mouse point, but with the smallest of movement it will create the following effect:

[Fully zoomed in, click a couple of pixels right of centre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRk88.jpg)

**UPDATE AND WORKING... FOR NOW**

At the time of generating the texture for my map I also generate an alternative texture which represents each "tile" as a different colour. In my initial and current attempt the colour of this tile is a function of it's X and Y coordinates ( a map is made up of 100 tiles across and 100 tiles down, so the x+y coordinates range from 0 - 99 )

I end up with a texture which looks like a gradient from green to red. The below code will, at the time of a mouse click, quickly render this texture ( imperceptible to user ) and read the rgb value under the mouse. We then turn that rgb value into a world coordinate and BOOM... the relative coordinates of my map are realised.

```
float pX, pY;

// render a colourised version of the scene for the purposes of "picking"
// https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/selection.htm
public void pick ( GL2 gl2 ) {

    // DRAW PICKING SCENE
    gl2.glClearBufferfv(GL2.GL_COLOR, 0, clearColor);
    gl2.glClearBufferfv(GL2.GL_DEPTH, 0, clearDepth);
    gl2.glTranslatef( -cameraX, -cameraY, -cameraZ );

    // draw my map but use the colour gradient texture
    for ( Entity e : this.entities ) {
        e.drawPick( gl2 );
    }

    // not sure what this does #cargo-cult
    gl2.glFlush();
    gl2.glFinish();
    gl2.glPixelStorei(GL2.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);


    // After rendering ask OpenGL to read the colour of the screen at the given window coordinates!
    FloatBuffer buffer = FloatBuffer.allocate(4);

    int realy = 0; 
    int viewport[] = new int[4];
    gl2.glGetIntegerv(GL2.GL_VIEWPORT, viewport, 0);
    realy = viewport[3] - (int) mouse.getY() - 1;

    gl2.glReadPixels( mouse.getX(), realy, 1, 1, GL2.GL_RGBA, GL2.GL_FLOAT, buffer);
    float[] pixels = new float[3];
    pixels = buffer.array();

    // pixels holds rgb values respectively
    // convert the red + green values back into x + y values
    pX = (pixels[0] * 255) - 25f;
    pY = -((pixels[1] * 255) - 25f);

    // draw the proper texture
    for ( Entity e : this.entities ) {
        e.draw( gl2 );
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't consider myself an elder at all, but I am pretty sure they would say to avoid [deprecated opengl](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL). The logic steps seem right, though.

Comment: Perspective projection mode might be (one of) the issue. Is there a reason for that? Orthographic sounds more approriate to me..

Comment: Thanks for replying, I use VAO and glDrawElements for the rendering proper ( i.e. my map ). I have experimented with glOrtho but found it unintuitive to implement zooming. I would probably relate my issue with implementing mouse clicking in 3D games in general. I have updated my question with the opengl init settings

Comment: Use "GLU.createGLU(GL)" rather than "new GLU()". Have a look at our example of picking: jogamp.org/jogl-demos/src/demos/misc/Picking.java Please provide a SSCCE if you still need help.

Comment: Interesting, so you make a decision on where the mouse has clicked based on the colour of the pixel under the mouse pointer? It seems quite perverted that it should be the way we go about mouse clicking but I like it! Would it be suitable for me, on the event of a mouse click, to render a special colourised version of my map which would be pre-buffered, then read the colour, decide which "tile" of the map has been clicked and then render the map proper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You've almost got it. You're going to need a good value for Z in the unproject function though.**

What you are trying to do is take the position of the cursor and multiply by a matrix to give a point in "3d space". Your matrices are likely 4x4 or 4x3, so you need a 4 component vector. (x,y,z,w)

When you draw your map, the existing point is multiplied by 1 or more matrices including the projection matrix. ( e.g. `-25.0f,25.0f,0.0f,1.0f` - actually a 3d point). When this is multiplied by all matrices, the GPU essentially gets back a value in normalised device coordinates (NDC) (between -1 and 1 in all axes) for that vertex.

To do the opposite and unproject you'll need to have a valid/good value for Z. The reason is that in NDC everything that is drawn is in -1,1 on all axes, to get everything in (further away things are squashed a bit). This is how you get flickering and weirdness if you have a huge > 100000 zFar distance for example, it still has to fit into -1,1.

The best way to do this is to use the depth buffer, by capturing the depth value it'll give you a good approxomation of the z coordinate in NDC, which you can pass to the unproject call.

The reason why 0.945 is the sweet spot is probably dependent on  how far the camera is from your map or vice versa. It's usually the case that the depth buffer has much more detail closer to the near plane than the far - it's not linear.

http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/ has a good visual near the bottom of the page, and is a good resource for intro to matrices in general:
[image: link below]
[image: link below]

You can see the distortion caused by moving to NDC. This is required for viewing from a perspactive viewpoint, but you need to take it into consideration when you transform backward too.

Colour picking as mentioned is also viable for picking, but will still require some work. Because you have a single object, you'll have to render each texel of the image with a different colour, output that to a separate colour buffer, check to see what colour is on the buffer and somehow relate that to a point in space. It could probably be done though, but I'd say colour picking is more suited to multiple objects.

From what I've read - the depth buffer one might be more suitable for you as it's one object, and the depth buffer will give you a Z coordinate for every point you click on. It could still be on your far plane, but it will still give you a value.

Alternatively, as suggested by @elect use an orthographic projection.

Comment: Thanks for a good explanation. I will spend some time over each method and see how I get on.